# Prototype of Constructor Function

Tags: javascript

Recently I come to this quiz related to Javascript prototypes and the answer of which I think are both true.

Suppose the variable Tool is a function. What will Tool.prototype return?

A) The prototype object for the instances of Tool.
B) The prototype object of the function Tool.

The result shows that option A is correct which makes sense but also option B given that we are talking about same thing here.

Comment: maybe for B they were thinking of `Object.getProtoTypeOf(Tool)`?

Comment: @qrsngky does constructor function' prototype is something different then the the prototype of the constructor function instances? Give that we don't change the prototype of constructor function? I'm confirming from you because I started learning prototypes recently and was practicing problems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you run `Tool.prototype.something = "something"` then make an instance, you can `console.log(instance)` and it will see the prototype includes that. And you can use `instance.something`. However, `Tool.something` is undefined, but Tool does have prototypal inheritance from Function like `.apply` and `.call` (i.e. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Tool).call` is a function). So, Tool.apply and Tool.call are functions. In contrast, the instances don't have direct access to apply or call

Comment: `Function.prototype` is a prototype of functions. `Tool.prototype` will always and only be a prototype of object instances created by the function. No chances B is correct here.

Comment: If by B they meant `Object.getProtoTypeOf(Tool)`, then it's obviously not the same as A (`Tool.prototype`)

Comment: @WiktorZychla can you kindly elaborate little more? Given the current example, I believe both will be same. I mean the function's prototype is the prototype with the same name as of function which will also be the prototype of all instances using the constructor function.

Comment: @SaadAli Wrote an answer, hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this deserves an answer, since the OP sounds to confuse things.

> Given the current example, I believe both will be same. I mean the function's prototype is the prototype with the same name as of function which will also be the prototype of all instances using the constructor function.

Let's start with a constructor function

```
function Tool() { }
```

Now, consider the `Tool.prototype`. This object is attached as a prototype to instances newly constructed with the constructor function.

The

> A) The prototype object for the instances of Tool.

is correct then, easy to check

```js
function Tool() { }

var t = new Tool();

console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(t) === Tool.prototype );
```

But how can

> B) The prototype object of the function Tool.

be true?

What's the prototype of the `Tool` function?

Well, the object that is a prototype of a function has to contain `call`, `bind` or `apply`. Where would these come from in `Tool.prototype`?

The actual prototype of `Tool` is the `Function.prototype` and this can easily be checked

```js
function Tool() { }

console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf( Tool ) === Function.prototype )
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf( Tool ) === Tool.prototype )

console.log( Function.prototype.call )
console.log( Tool.prototype.call )
```

The last snippet not only shows that `Function.prototype` is actual prototype of `Tool` but also that it really has the `call` (and other) methods specific to functions which the `Tool.prototype` lacks.

**Edit** Yet another piece, maybe this will help.

Most Javascript objects have their prototypes. Create an empty object, a function - their prototypes are set. You already know that. A prototype is always used when properties are accessed.

The prototype of any object can be retrieved with `Object.getPrototypeOf(...)`.

**Functions** are objects and as all other objects, they have their prototype, the `Function.prototype` is the prototype object of all functions.

However **constructor functions** are special. Not only they have their own prototype (the `Function.prototype`) but also, there's yet another prototype involved - the prototype that will be attached to newly created instances.

The two prototypes, the prototype of the function object itself and the prototype attached to newly created instances are two very distinct prototypes.

Take this example

```js
// (1) take a constructor function
function Tool() {}

// (2) modify the prototype it attaches to newly created instances
Tool.prototype.foo = 1;

// (3) create an instance
var t = new Tool();

// (4) this prints 1, the prototype from (2) is attached to t
console.log( t.foo ); // 1

// (5) but, the prototype from (2) is NOT attached to Tool
// this prints 'undefined'
var toolPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf( Tool );
console.log( toolPrototype.foo ); // undefined

// (6) if we attach something to toolPrototype
// (the prototype of the function object)
toolPrototype.bar = 17;

// (7) then Tool has it
console.log( Tool.bar ); // 17

// (8) as well as all other functions
// (because we have modified the Function.prototype)!
console.log( console.log.bar ); // 17

// but instances created by Tool have a separate chain (they have 'foo')
console.log( t.bar ); // undefined
```

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor for the detailed answer. As I said, I'm kind of beginner into Prototypes and took a course on Pluralsight where instructor said that the 'Function's prototype is the object instance that will be the prototype of the instances created using this constructor function'. So, is this statement half true. Right? I mean the function's own prototype is actually not that?

Comment: @SaadAli This cited statement is perfectly true and it refers to the clause A of your question. I guess you could be tricked by how words are picked here. *Function's prototype* is always referred to this `Tool.prototype` here, the object that is attached to newly constructed instances. However, the `Tool` function is an object and it has its own prototype, the `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @SaadAli: There's a difference between the two: while you often want to alter the `Tool.prototype` (prototype object of your custom constructor function), you never (or barely) touch the actual prototype of the function object (the `Function.prototype`).

Comment: @SaadAli: another way of thinking of this is: every Javascript object has a prototype. It can be obtained by calling `Object.getPrototypeOf( o )` where `o` is the object. However, a constructor function has yet another *prototype* attached - this prototype is not the prototype of the constructor function itself, but it is used as a prototype of newly created instances and you refer to it as `F.prototype`.

Comment: @SaadAli I believe I could edit my question to reflect that last remark.

Comment: Thank you for the clear description and taking a time to write this answer. The option B is definitely not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the function's prototype with the function's property named `prototype`.
They are different things.

The function's prototype (as the prototype of any object) can be retrieved using [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

The property `prototype` is present only for functions and it is the object that becomes the prototype of the objects created when the function is used as a constructor:

```js
function Tool() { ...}

const t = new Tool();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(t) === Tool.prototype);
// true
```

Read about [object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in the JavaScript documentation.